# MYSQL error 1064 in select clause

Tags: php, sql

As I am beginner so I am facing syntax error in this query.

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email = ".$email." AND password = ".$password."";
```

Comment: Give quotes to strings & show your complete error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one, you should use single quote.

`$SQL = "SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email = '".$email."' AND password = '".$password."'";`

Answer (score 4):

You have syntax error with the query. Try to change it to

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".$password."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Put single quote to value field like this

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM registration
           WHERE email = '".$email."' AND password ='".$password."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

you should put single quote before and after the variable.

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email = '".$email."' AND password = '".$password."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
```

Try this..

Comment: I voted up for you because it does work , but yes you need to tell the OP to stop using a deprecated database API.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string and string should be wrapped in single quotes. Try this -

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email = '".$email."' AND password = '".$password."'";
```